# Logictic Regression can't fit my data

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I'm trying fit my data , but I couldn't fit it.Data set

```
0.50,0
0.75,0
1.00,0
1.25,0
1.50,0
1.75,0
1.75,1
2.00,0
2.25,1
2.50,0
2.75,1
3.00,0
3.25,1
3.50,0
4.00,1
4.25,1
4.50,1
4.75,1
5.00,1
5.50,1
```

and my code

```
data = np.loadtxt('dat', delimiter=',',dtype=None);

x=data[:,0:1];
y=data[:,1].reshape(x.size/x[0].size,1);
a=np.ones(shape=(y.size,x[0].size+1));
a[:,1:2]=x;
q=np.ones(shape=(a.shape[1],1));
alpha=0.003

for i in range(500000):
    h=1/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(a,q)))
    for j in range(q.size):
        q[j][0]=q[j][0]-alpha*np.sum((h-y)*a[:,j]);
plt.axis((-1,10,-1,5))
plt.plot(x,y,'x',x,h);
plt.show();
```

So I tried different learning rates(alpha),tried different number of iterations but my fitting data is looking like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ILNe.png)

but it's should looks like this [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#/media/File:Exam_pass_logistic_curve.jpeg)

What am I missing? Is there any logical error or something like that? Thanks for your deal.

Comment: This question might be better answered on cross validated. Its not really a code issue, but rather an implementation issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm overall looks correct, there seems to be a small issue with the `numpy` implementation, when you calculated `(h - y)*a`, you did

```
    q[j][0] = q[j][0] - alpha * np.sum((h - y) * a[:,j])
```

But because you are using `numpy.ndarray` types not `numpy.matrix` type, you should have done e.g. `a[:, j].dot(h - y)`

```
    q[j][0] = q[j][0] - alpha * np.sum(a[:,j].dot(h - y))
```

Here's what I got from your plot after the fitting is done

[image]